# I2C on stm32f407 doesn't work

Tags: stm32, i2c, stm32f4discovery

I wrote a program to use I2C with stm32f407vgt on my board but it doesn't work. I checked the clock(scl) and it was OK , then i tested the same program on stm32f429 discovery board without changing any settings and it worked. any idea about what should i do ?

my micro is stm32f407 and i use internal clock source.

Thanks hamid

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. I read another question and understood that one. What is wrong?

Comment: my code works on another micro but in my board doesn't work .micro and sensor connection directly but  it doesn't work and my micro is new

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe there are pullup already on 1 board and not on the other? Do you have a scope/logic analyzer to compare?

Comment: Which f407 board? Have you verified that the pins you're using on that board are actually free for your use?

Comment: Did you solved this issue, Or is this still open?